# how to count the days (mon,tue) from unix time in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array name,unixtime,page.

I am gathering stats and would like to know the days (mon,tues,wed) on which pages are looked at. I have already done this with the username (bob viewed 3 pages) using the using array_count_values() function. However I would have to convert the unix time into date('D',$unixtime); Without going into loops is there a clever way of doing this.

So this is my base code for counting the pages the user viewed. I now want to count the days on which page was viewed.

```
// Get number of times user requested a page
$user_request_array = array();
$user_request_array = array_count_values(array_column($array, 0));
arsort($user_request_array);
$user_request_key_array = array_keys($user_request_array);
$y = 0;
foreach ($user_request_array as $user_request_stat_line) {
$user_request_stats .= $user_request_key_array[$y].': 
<strong>'.$user_request_stat_line.'</strong><br>';
$y++;
}
```

Any ideas on doing this in a clever way or do I start looping?
Thanks.

Comment: unix time you'd strtotime($time) then use $date('D',$time), but you need to loop the array to change each element containing this time there's no way without a loop to go through each element in an arra once it's there

Comment: I discovered array_count_values() and its WOW 99% of my job done, all I need is something like array_count_values_as_date() lol cheers.. * Just checked it doesnt exist. Dont worry I am not looking for someone to write me a function just a clever built in function if one exists.

Comment: Is this data coming from a database?

Comment: It's a simple 4 line loop that will convert the unix to a day..it's not hard.

Comment: Its coming from a csv logfile. I'll go the loop route wondered if any more clever functions existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I decided to do it in the end.

```
## I have a loop here creating tables from the data so...
// While we are here in the loop get the unix date and convert to day
$day_request_flat .= date('D',$log_line[5]).',';
}

// Create day stats.
$day_request_array = array(); // Define the array 
$day_request_flat  = rtrim($day_request_flat,','); // Remove the last comma
$day_request_array = explode(',', $day_request_flat); // make an array out of the comma separated variable.
$day_request_array = array_count_values($day_request_array); // Count stuff in the array
$day_request_key_array = array_keys($day_request_array); 
$y = 0;
foreach ($day_request_array as $day_request_stat_line) {
    $day_request_stats .= $day_request_key_array[$y].': <strong>'.$day_request_stat_line.'</strong><br>';
 $y++;
}
```